# Where is the origin (0, 0) of plane geometry of <a-entity /> in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

[Here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/geometry.html#built_in_geometries7_width-2) is the document for a-entity

You can create an a entity like this:

```
<a-entity geometry="primitive: plane; height: 10; width: 10" material="side: double"></a-entity>
```

My question is where is the origin (0, 0) of this created plane? height and width are specified, but no origin.

Answer (score 1):

The default position of `<a-entity>` is `0 0 0`.
Keep in mind, that when both the camera and the plane are at the same position, you might not see the plane (because it has no thickness).

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mv35yzwf/).